# How to share the text Area in White Board?  My White Board is in BigBlueButton 

Tags: apache-flex, bigbluebutton

I created a white board in Big Blue Button.  In that white board i created a text field.  Now I want to share the text field.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to share the activity of creating text field among all client. Then you need to send the mouse events along with coordinates to the server and then to connected clients.

> For text within textfiled, you can send the character as soon as you write and your text Area is shared And also see the links
>   [To ShareTextArea](https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/source/detail?r=1436&path=/branches/developers/bo/bigbluebutton-client/src/org/bigbluebutton/modules/whiteboard/model/component/Text.as)